# Changes in phtml not visible in the browser

Tags: magento2.2, cache, upgrade, phtml, permissions

When I change a .phtml it is not reflected in the browser until after approximately 24 hours.

I've tried everything, run `php bin/magento cache:flush`, check the permissions of magento_user.

I'm using Magento 2.2 on Apache tomcat

Has it happened to anyone else?

Comment: did you use cloudfare ??

Comment: have you set up varinsh with full page cache! ?

Comment: May i know if your website is on localhost or any third party hosting ?

Comment: Seems issue with you server cache, contact your server guy about this problem there must be a way to refresh cache on server. (I am not talking about Magento cache)

Comment: Its something similar with what i am currently facing.. i have magento2 setup up on nginx with varnish configured with full page cache magento. After each change in a phtml file, i have to restart varnish for it to apply. Even changing a static block content gets updated on the frontend after restarting varnish!

Answer (score 4):

`php bin/magento cache:flush` is used when you change `.php` files. When you change `.phtml` or `.XML` files you have to deploy static content.

try this,

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

and afterthat

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I already did what you said before but the problem continues.

Comment: That's not completely true.
- Xml changes are visible simply refreshing layout cache
- for phtml changes you need to run setup:static-content:deploy only if you have minified html and after removing pub/static/* and var/view_preprocessed, otherwise it isn't necessary

Comment: @DanieleRovatti heey, you seems like to talk some sense. Almost every tutorial and answer on the internet always advice to flush cache, clear cache, but sometimes it isn't' necessary. Do you have some sort of a resource to what needs to be cleared when? Would you be interested into making one?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove data from `pub\static\frontend`

and then run `php bin/magento s:s:d`

Clear data from

> var/cache
>
> Var/page_cache
>
> var/view_preprocessed

Check if you are on developer mode or production mode

Also try checking once in incognito window.

Comment: i do not think phtml files are deployed under static.. its .html, js, css

Comment: Thanks for your response, LAW.
I already did what you said before but the problem continues.
I'm in developer mode

Comment: I agree with you Hammand Khalid, what's more, the changes in CSS I see them correctly

Comment: It could be necessary if you have minified html enabled. This is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Give these commands,and run this in browser again.U can see it within seconds.

cd /bin

php magento setup:upgrade

php magento setup:di:compile

php magento setup:static-content:deploy –f

php magento cache:flush

Comment: Why setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile for phtml files? they aren't necessary unless you have installed a new module. Same for static-content deploy. You need to run for phtml only if you have minified html enabled

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the template hints for the site in the admin.

[image]

[image]

You will need to clear cache after you make this change. Right now you are assuming that you are editing the correct file. If caching is not the issue the odds are good you are editing the wrong template.

[image]

This has nothing to do with the deploy of static files. .phtml files are't served in the pub folder. The only relates to .js, .css and .html files.